# Geometric question involving integral of a function and its inverse.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

I am given a function $\phi(s)$, continuous and strictly increasing with $\phi(0) = 0$, and want to show that for all $a,b \geq 0$, $$ab \leq \int_0^a \phi(x)dx + \int_0^b \phi^{-1}(x)dx.$$ I know how to do this if $\phi$ is differentiable using an old integration by parts trick, but here I have no differentiability assumption. Any input or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint:** Draw it in the same coordinate system, as $y=\phi(x)$ and as $x=\phi^{-1}(y)$, observe that these give the same contour line, and look for the two pieces of area corresponding to the integrals.

Comment: Thanks for this. I realized as soon as I posted, but it was great to get such quick confirmation.